# requests: ошибка 405 при попытке запроса

Tags: python, requests

```
import requests

url = "https://www.regard.ru/price/regard_priceList.xlsx"
headers = {'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:85.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/85.0"}

s.get(url, headers=headers)
<Response [200]>
# получаю ошибку
f = open("https://www.regard.ru/price/regard_priceList.xlsx", "wb")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'https://www.regard.ru/price/regard_priceList.xlsx'
# А вот при другом запросе 405
s.post(url, headers=headers)
<Response [405]>
```

Как скачать файл ?

Answer (score 1):

> Как скачать файл?

```py
import requests

PATH = 'regard_priceList.xlsx'
URL = 'https://www.regard.ru/price/regard_priceList.xlsx'
HEADERS = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:85.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/85.0'}

resp = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS)
with open(PATH, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(resp.content)
```

где `PATH` — путь для сохранения файла.